# Xamarin Android in Visual Studio -- fsproj file stores the device I ran in the debugger

Tags: f#, xamarin.android

I've got a Xamarin Android project, written in F# (and I suspect I will encounter a similar problem in C#).

I always debug the app on a device, for various reasons. After disconnecting my phone from my PC, the fsproj file changed as follows:

```
-    <SelectedDevice>Samsung SM-G925F</SelectedDevice>
+    <SelectedDevice>10.1" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Tablet</SelectedDevice>
```

I must say, I am rather surprised that this is still happening in Visual Studio. Clearly, it is very bad for collaboration if the project file gets re-written every time I debug the project with a new device.

Is there a setting I can apply that prevents this from happening?